# what does the set $(wc -l $title_file) mean in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

These days.i'm learning the shell script for fun.When i read the manual's example like:

```
set $(wc -l $title_file)
  num_titles=$1
  set $(wc -l $tracks_file)
  num_tracks=$1
```

And i have the brief understanding that the command,set,specify the $1 and set the value of $1 to the num_titles.
But,i have no idea why use -l as the option for the command,set.And by the way,would any guy can explain the whole story of it?thx

Comment: This example is bizarre.  It would be much more common to skip the set command and simply write: num_titles=$( wc -l $title_file )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `set` sets an environment variable.
Using the syntax `set var = value` or `set var [n] = word` as per its manpage , to view the manpage type `man set`.

In this case set is using the second syntax to make `$1 = $(wc -1 $titlefile)` and then setting num_titles to $1 as a regular variablle because of the syntax used.

`wc` is the wordcount command, and displays lines, characters and words in a file.

`wc -l` tells wc to count by line as per the wc manpage, to view the manpage type `man wc`.

See the [Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial A Beginner's handbook](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/) and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for further references.

Comment: i got it,thx.And by the way,whenever,by default,i use the command,set,it will set the new value as the first arg?

Comment: Yes that is correct as per set man page clause `The  remaining
     arguments  are  positional  parameters  and are assigned, in
     order, to $1, $2, .... `

Comment: In sh, 'set' does not use the syntax described here.  In csh, the syntax used here sets a variable, but not an environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

the -l switch is counting the number of lines in the specified file(s)
in your case, it is counting the number of lines in the titles file and setting it to the num_titles variable (and counting the number of lines in the file specified by the tracks_file variable and setting the value to num_track variable)

you can simply try
wc  -l  
on the command line to see the value it prints out

Comment: i got it,thx.And by the way,whenever,by default,i use the command,set,it will set the new value as the first arg?

Comment: yes. So if you do **set a b c** variable $1 is now equal to "a", $2=b, and $3=c